# Select the row with the second-highest value inside a group

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have a table as such (`tbl`):

```
+----+-----+------+-----+
| pk | grp | attr | val |
+----+-----+------+-----+
|  0 |   0 | ohif |   4 |
|  1 |   0 | foha |  56 |
|  2 |   0 | slns |   2 |
|  3 |   1 | faso |  11 |
|  4 |   1 | tepj |   4 |
|  5 |   2 | bnda |  12 |
|  6 |   2 | ojdf |   9 |
|  7 |   2 | anaw |   1 |
+----+-----+------+-----+
```

I would like to select one row from each group, in particular that with the second-highest `val` for each group.

I.e., I want this table:

```
+----+-----+------+-----+
| pk | grp | attr | val |
+----+-----+------+-----+
|  1 |   0 | ohif |   4 |
|  3 |   1 | tepj |   4 |
|  5 |   2 | ojdf |   9 |
+----+-----+------+-----+
```

This is the solution I came up with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (grp)
pk,
(
    SELECT innertbl.grp
    FROM tbl AS innertbl
    WHERE innertbl.grp = tbl.grp
    ORDER BY innertbl.val DESC
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
) AS grp,
(
    SELECT innertbl.attr
    FROM tbl AS innertbl
    WHERE innertbl.grp = tbl.grp
    ORDER BY innertbl.val DESC
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
) AS attr,
(
    SELECT innertbl.val
    FROM tbl AS innertbl
    WHERE innertbl.grp = tbl.grp
    ORDER BY innertbl.val DESC
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
) AS val
FROM tbl
```

However this is inefficient as it requires a subquery for each column to select, for each group.

I'm on Postgres 10.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a window function inside of a sub-query to get what you need:

```
SELECT
    pk, grp, attr, val
FROM (
    SELECT
        pk, grp, attr, val,
        row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY val DESC) AS seq
    FROM
        tbl
    ) data
WHERE
    seq = 2
```

row_number() provides a sequence within the group (using PARTITION BY).

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Nick was what I was going to post, but to add one thing I'd say if you want to skip over duplicates you can use the [dense_rank](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) function:

```
SELECT pk, grp, attr, val FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY val DESC) AS seqnum
  FROM
    mytable
) t WHERE seqnum = 2;
```